# angularjs performance in ng-repeat combined with ng-if

Tags: javascript, angularjs, optimization, angularjs-ng-repeat

My case is pretty easy to explain: I have an array of objects (50-250 elements) that I use to populate a table, but I need to visualize only a part of them. Rows to visualize change at runtime based on user click.

To sum up my code will be something like this

```
<div ng-repeat="position in positions track by $index" ng-if="position.display" >
    <!-- my code here -->
</div>
```

The point is that `position.display` is a property to be calculated each time the user trigger events. So I have 2 choices

1. Loop on positions at each user to calculate if `position.display` must be `true` or `false`.

   ```
   $scope.userTriggerEvent = function() {
       positions.forEach(function(position) {
           if (...) { position.display = true; } else { position.display = false; }
       });
   }
   ```
2. Use a function to be called inside `ng-if` that take `position` as argument and return `true` or `false`

   ```
   <div ng-repeat="position in positions track by $index" ng-if="displayMe(position)">

   $scope.displayMe = function(position) {
       if (...) { return true; } else { return false; }
   }
   ```

Considering how angular handle check on `ng-if` which is better?
My guess is the first, because angular have to check only a variable and not the output of a function, but maybe I'm wrong and angular optimize in a different way

Comment: basically you want to limit your values to display ?

Comment: yes, but that is straightforward, I want to know whick of the 2 valid solutions should grant better performance

Comment: You could even use `limitTo`  filter to achieve the same, which is even better than above two methods.